# hook_views_data Join by multiple value field

Tags: views

I need retrive data from a custom table in drupal db by a colum that match with a drupal field in a content type.

I have this table:
**equipages

id_equipage|description|price|status**

The *id_equipage* is a varchar and is unique.
**records example**:
cliowave123abs|ABS of my Renault Clio|150|1
cliowave123oth|Some other option of my Renault Clio|10|1
cliowave123air|Air cond of my Renault Clio|250|1
meganeliveabs|ABS of my Renault Megane|310|1

Now I have a content type called *car* whit a text field *equipages* (table field_data_equipages) with unlimited values.
In this field I add all the id_equipage of the car.
So for example I have a node (nid: 5) like this:
Title: Clio Wave 2013
equipages:
1. cliowave123abs
2. cliowave123air

Now, When I read the node (nid: 5), I want retrive the 2 records from my custom table
cliowave123abs|ABS of my Renault Clio|150|1
cliowave123air|Air cond of my Renault Clio|250|1

Can I do this whit the hook_views_data()??

Can you help me?!

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like pretty standard fare to me? Which part do you have problems with? Describing the table itself or describing the join?

Comment: The join. If I add a view of content i cant add the column of my custom table because doesn't exist relationship.

Comment: I need something like this
SELECT
 c.*
FROM 
 field_data_field_equipages a

JOIN node b ON a.entity_id = b.nid AND a.entity_type = 'node'
JOIN equipages c ON a.field_equipages_value = c.id_equipage
WHERE nid = 9

Answer (score 2):

I believe this https://www.drupal.org/node/810932#comment-3020000 comment describes exactly what you need which is the `extra` field in a join description:

```
$data['node']['table']['join'] = array(
  // this explains how the 'node' table (named in the line above)
  // links toward the node_revision table.
  'node_revision' => array(
    'left_field' => 'nid',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'extra' => array(array('field' => 'fieldname', 'value' => 'value', 'operator' => '='))
 ),
```

);

Comment: Thanks... The problem is that in my custom table (equipages) I have not nid column. My foreign key is the id_equipage that has to join with the table field_data_field_equipages.

Comment: just add 'field'.